# Code to create Azure VM using Azure Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-compute-emulator

I need to create a Azure Virtual Machine using Azure Java SDK. I wants either code of some guideline for creating VM step by step.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a Q&A site designed to help with specific problems, if you are stuck with a specific bit of code then post that and tell us why it isn't working. Otherwise this question will likely be closed as being too broad. P.S. have you tried the [docs](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/)[http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/]

Answer (score 1):

As I known, there are two ways for creating VM using Azure Java SDK. You can refer to their different REST APIs and authenticating request to know them.

1. Create VM using Azure Resource Management ([VM REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163647.aspx) require [Authenticating Resource Manager Requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx))
2. Create VM (classic) using Azure Service Management ([VM classic REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157206.aspx) require [Authenticating Service Management Requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460782.aspx))

I recommend the first one to create an Azure VM. There is a offical sample code on GitHub, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/samples/compute/CreateVMExample.java.

As reference, the steps are as below.

1. Create a `Configuration`, please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/azure-mgmt-samples/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/samples/authentication/ServicePrincipalExample.java to know more details.
2. Create these client like `ResourceManagementClient`, `StorageManagementClient`, `ComputeManagementClient` & `NetworkResourceProviderClient` using the `Configuration`.
3. Create the `ResourceContent` using `ResouceGroupName` & `Region`.
4. Create a VM via the function `createVM` of the Helper [`ComputeHelper`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/resource-management/azure-mgmt-utility/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/utility/ComputeHelper.java).

You also can refer to the javadocs of the package `com.microsoft.azure.management` for Azure Java SDK at http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/.